# Inequality exercise with floor function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In one book I found the following exercise

$\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor\leq \frac{x-1}{3}$

where $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor$ is Floor Function

To solve it makes $\frac{x-1}{3}=n\in \mathbb{Z}$,  therefore it uses the property $\left \lfloor x \right \rfloor\leq n\Leftrightarrow x< n+1$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ coming to the solution set $\left \{ -2,-5,-8,... \right \}$

I think this is not the right solution, for example the inequality is true if $x=-5.7$

$\left \lfloor -5.7 \right \rfloor=-6$ then $-6\leq \frac{-5.7-1}{3}=-2.333$.

So $-6\leq -2.333$

Also  the inequality is true for $x=-3$, because $-3\leq \frac{-4}{3}=-1.33$

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why is $n=(x-1)/3$?

Comment: Try sketching a graph of the two functions.

Comment: I guess the book's solution works if the $\leq$ is changed to $=$.  Maybe it's a misprint.  Otherwise, you're right.